# find and replace a string in xml using batch

Tags: batch-file

Sample input:

```xml
<ClCompile> 
<PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader> 
<WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
<Optimization>Disabled</Optimization> 
<SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck> 
<PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_WINDOWS;_DEBUG;NEWCODE;% (PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
</ClCompile>
```

Intended output:

```xml
<ClCompile> 
<PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader> 
<WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
<Optimization>Disabled</Optimization> 
<SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck> 
<PreprocessorDefinitions>_LARGE_;WIN32;_WINDOWS;_DEBUG;NEWCODE;% (PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
</ClCompile>
```

Current output when running batch multiple times:

```xml
<ClCompile> 
<PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader> 
<WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
<Optimization>Disabled</Optimization> 
<SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck> 
<PreprocessorDefinitions>_LARGE;_LARGE_;WIN32;_WINDOWS;_DEBUG;NEWCODE;% (PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
</ClCompile>
```

Batch file:

```batch-file
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
        
set "textFile="C:\"
set "file2=%textFile%\sample.vcxproj"
set list=%file2%
set "WIN32=^<PreprocessorDefinitions^>"
set "LARGE_=_LARGE_;"
set  "replace=%WIN32%_LARGE_;"
set "cmd=%1"
set "append=enable"
set "remove=disable"
set "empty="
echo %replace% !WIN32!
(for %%a in (%list%) do (
        IF "%cmd%"=="%remove%" (
            echo removed
            for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type %%a ^& break ^> %%a ') do (
                set "line=%%i"
                setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
                >>"%%a" echo(!line:%LARGE_DICOM%=%empty%!
                endlocal
            )
        )

        IF "%cmd%"=="%append%" (
            echo append

            echo %%a
            for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type %%a ^& break ^> %%a ') do (
                set "line=%%i"

                Echo "%%i" |findstr /R "%replace%" 1>nul
                if  %errorlevel%==0 (
                    echo eexist
                )


                setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
                >>"%%a" echo(!line:%WIN32%=%replace%!
                endlocal
            )
        )
        echo %%a

    ))
```

I am trying to find `LARGE` in `preprocessor`, if not exist add it, but it is adding multiple times
Find and, search is not working.  I need to append only if it not exist.
Append to file if particular sting not found, string should append once, even if we run batch multiple times.

Comment: if some one is new, then might me having doubt. if any suggestion please, otherwise ignore.. thanks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That question was closed not by me, that is why removed. Thanks for your help

Comment: <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_WINDOWS;_DEBUG;NEWCODE;% (PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions> This is single line of xml format <>

Comment: IMO, the first thing you should do is determine whether the file contains the string to append or remove, before attempting to enable or disable it. If the end user inputs `enable` and the file already has the string `;_LARGE_;` or `>_LARGE_;` on a line containing the string `<PreProcessorDefinitions>`, then end the script. If the end user inputs `disable` and the file does not already have the string `;_LARGE_;` or `>_LARGE_;` on a line containing the string `<PreProcessorDefinitions>`, then end the script. This way the file content is only rewritten when necessary. `findstr /?` should help.